# Weird PHP method behavior does not exist but is in code

Tags: php, static-methods, php-5.2

Does anyone have a clue about this?  PHP 5.2.13.  Results not wholly consistent i.e. could get a good result with a page at one time, then get an error at another.

The error is fatal - class does not have method.

But the following are true:

The class is defined in only one place and has the relevant method in the code.
At the point where failure occurs: reflection shows that the method exists.
At the point where failure occurs: method_exists says the method does not exist.
Previous calls (they're all static - not my choice) earlier in the code worked.

Comment: Could you show some code?

Comment: The original code is part of Joomla and is simply:
' jimport( 'joomla.application.router' );
 $router =& JRouter::getInstance($name, $options);'
Added to that have been diagnostics to show that the class JRouter exists after the first line, and the create a reflection class and call and dump getMethods() which shows that getInstance is a method of JRouter (as does inspection of the code).

Answer (score 1):

May be it's related: http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=51425

But I think here we have some cache-related problem. Do you have some cache enabled? Like APC or any other accelerators?

Comment: I've also suffered from method_exists problems in 5.3.x although this doesn't seem too similar.  My problem with method_exists is that it segfaults when called with a class name for a class that does not exist (should simply return false).  Curiously someone must know about the problem because Debian 5.3.3+ and 5.3.6+ both work correctly.  But this problem isn't a segfault, but a PHP fatal error message.  And the diagnostics are contradictory.  Very odd.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that the file containing the method is included. If the method is in a class, make sure the class instance is created and the method is called through the class.

Maybe you are missing the class instance?

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  The class is shown as existing by dumping class_exists() along with other diagnostics.  The method in question is static, and therefore does not rely on the class being instantiated.

Comment: Are the functions private in your static class?